# Using Selenium and BS4 is it possible to scrape the text outside the "=" within the div tag

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am looking at scraping the below information using both selenium and bs4, and was wondering if I find the below div tag, is it possible to scrape the data inside the quotation marks? for exmaple: `data-room-type-code="SUK"`

```html
<div
  class="sl-flexbox room-price-item  hidden-top-border"
  data-room-name="Superior Shard Room"
  data-bed-type="K"
  data-bed-name="King"
  data-pay-type-tag-filter="No Prepayment"
  data-cancel-tag-filter=""
  data-breakfast-tag-filter=""
  data-room-type-code="SUK"
  data-rate-code="ZBAR"
  data-price="430"
>
  <div class="room-price-basic-info">
    <div class="room-price-title title-regular">Flexible Rate / CustomStay</div>
    <ul class="abstract text-regular">
      <li>No Prepayment</li>
    </ul>
    <div
      class="show-detail text-btn js-show-detail"
      data-index="0-productRates-0"
    >
      OFFER DETAILS
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="room-price-book-info">
    <div class="number text-medium">GBP 430</div>
  </div>
  <div class="boot-btn text-medium js-booking-room" data-type="PRICE">
    Book Now
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can try this driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-bed-name='King']).get_attribute("data-room-type-code")                                                                as you can see, you need to add .get_attribute("data-room-type-code") at the end.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you want to get that value you can first loop through the `div` elements and then use  `div['data-room-type-code`]`.

Comment: Thank you both for the help much appreciated. Calling the attribute in the below way is exactly what I was looking for:

   `for posts in soup.findAll ('div',{'class':'sl-flexbox room-price-item'}):
        print(posts['data-room-name'])
        print(posts['data-price'])`